# Error while uploading mapping file to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, crashlytics

When building a release build with Crashlytics integration, the build is failing with the following exception:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileDevRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Unknown error while sending file, check network [/Users/sandbox/XXX/yyy-app/build/app/crashlytics/DevRelease/mappings/9c7dbabd823a461696881026a7fef145.gz; response: 500 HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error]
```

This appears to be caused by an internal server error when uploading the deofuscation mapping file to Crashlytics.

Comment: I have the same issue!

Comment: It's also happening to me, it would be nice if this issue could be reopened.

Comment: If anyone posts debugging details, such as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), this question would be reopened.

Comment: The network error has just disappeared, so I think it was a Firebase Crashlytics internal error